# Spring <form:select> doesn't print anything

Tags: java, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am  trying to print simple list values to the select box using spring controller. It successfully returns all values by using

```
${test}
```

but while I am trying this it not works. Solution will appreciate.

controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/flight", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView homePage(CountryCodes country) {
    //model.addAttribute("userName", user.getUserName());
    /*List<CountryCodes> countryCodes = userService.getCountryCodes();
    model.addAttribute("codes", countryCodes);*/

    ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("FlightDetails");
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add("Human Resources");
    test.add("Finance");
    test.add("Admin");
    test.add("Quality Assurance");
    test.add("Products");

    mv.addObject("test", test);
    return mv;
}
```

select box in jsp

```
   ${test}
<form:select path="country" class="form-control"> 
    <form:options items="${test}"  class="form-control"/> 
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the `spring:form` taglib reference? This way works for me:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/flight", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ModelAndView homePage(CountryCodes country) {
        //model.addAttribute("userName", user.getUserName());
        /*List<CountryCodes> countryCodes = userService.getCountryCodes();
        model.addAttribute("codes", countryCodes);*/

        ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("FlightDetails");
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        test.add("Human Resources");
        test.add("Finance");
        test.add("Admin");
        test.add("Quality Assurance");
        test.add("Products");

        mv.addObject("test", test);
        mv.addObject("country", country);
        return mv;
    }
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Select options from controller</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Select options from controller</h1>
            ${test}
            <form:select path="country" class="form-control"> 
                <form:options items="${test}"  class="form-control"/> 
            </form:select>
        </body>

    </html>
```